# What exactly is 最多?

Tags: meaning

I can't wrap my head around the usage of 最多 in the following:

> 一日の感染者数の最多を更新しました

According to jisho (https://jisho.org/search/%E6%9C%80%E5%A4%9A) 最多 is a noun meaning "the most", but the above usage suggests it can be updated. So it does not reflect the English word "most".

If I were to form a sentence, I would go with "update the number" or "update the record" like below:

> 一日の感染者の最多数を更新しました
>
> 一日の感染者数の最多記録を更新しました

But I would never think of "update the most" concept.

What exactly is 最多 in Japanese?

Comment: Related?: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21296/7810

Comment: Also, does the grammar section of the Wiktionary article clear up things for you? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A4%9A%E3%81%84

Comment: I see no relation and Wiktionary does not clear up the things. How can you "update the most"? It is object of the verb 更新する, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm... Are you feeling uncomfortable only with 最多 or generally 最○? For example, what about 平均株価は今年最低を記録した?

Comment: Generally with 最○. 平均株価は今年最低を記録した looks fine to me.

Answer (score 4):

最多 is "the most (in numbers)".

But "一日の感染者数" means "the number of people infected PER DAY".

So it's NOT talking about the number of people infected IN TOTAL.

For example: One day 10 people get infected. Another day maybe 12, other 8. In that case, "一日の感染者数の最多" would be 12. Now, yesterday 20 people newly get infected, so it can be said 一日の感染者数の最多が更新された.

On the other hand, in the sentences "感染者の最多数を更新しました" and "感染者数の最多記録を更新しました", 感染者数 refers to the total number of people infected.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Yes. I already mentioned it means "the most" per dictionary. Then, how can you "update the most?" It is the object of 更新する, right? And I was not asking whether it is per day, or total.

Comment: @szczupaczek Just because "update the most" is unnatural in English doesn't make this unnatural. The concept is easy to grasp, even if the wording would be strange translated literally.