# 山には多く雪があります。 what does ”は” after ”に” mean?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-は, help

Why can't I say ”山に多い雪があります”? What does ”は” after ”に” mean?

Comment: Unrelated to the は but I wonder if you noticed that you used 多い in one sentence and 多く in the other?

Comment: Does it help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF

Comment: @user3856370 yes, it was my second mistake in this sentence.. I know that is 多く mean and understend phrase 多く雪, but still can't understand why can't i say 多い雪.  one girl told me how exactly this sentence write but she didn't tell why. i have some troubles with grammar.. thanks for correcting my english!

Comment: @ニ　カ Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59713/7810

Comment: Be careful. That 多く acts adverbially on あります. It does not act on 雪. These links should help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/how-is-the-adjective-%e5%a4%9a%e3%81%84-being-used-as-a-noun-%e5%a4%9a%e3%81%8f-here and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66648/relative-clauses-%e5%a4%9a%e3%81%84%e4%ba%ba-vs-%e5%a4%9a%e3%81%8f%e3%81%ae%e4%ba%ba